# How to break a list into couple lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, reshape

Assume that I have a list with `size=(8,64,1,60,60)` and want to break it into `(4,2,64,1,60,60)` and then sum them up along axis 1. I tried the code below but it raised with error :

```
'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'.
```

Please note that I want to keep the predictions as a list and do not want to change it to array.

```
predictions=list(np.random.randint(5,size=(8,64,1,60,60)))
predictions_sum = predictions.reshape(4,2, *predictions.shape[1:]).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Python's built-in `list` type with `numpy`'s `array`. Try this:

```
predictions=np.array(np.random.randint(5,size=(8,64,1,60,60)))
predictions_sum = predictions.reshape(4,2, *predictions.shape[1:]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I mentioned that I want to keep the predictions as a list since I used predictions=[ ] as an 5D empty list to fill it with the matrix above.

Comment: Fair enough, but `list` is not a numpy type hence doesn't have the `.reshape` method.